# HighCharts mouseUp event after panning the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts with a timeline. The extremes points can be changed by:

- Moving the timeline bar
- or Panning inside the chart

I want to call "doSomeStuffs" only if the mouse is up.

If the user moves the timeline bar, at the end when the mouse is up, there is a mouseUp event. This is the expected behavior.

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function (e) {
            console.log("called many times");

            if (e.DOMEvent && e.DOMEvent.type == 'mouseup') {
                console.log("only called when the mouse is up");
                doSomeStuffs();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work in the case of panning inside the chart. There is no mouseUp event when the mouse is up. Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: How about checking a e.trigger type, like here http://jsfiddle.net/8ydfw9ma/

Comment: It doesn't work when you pan inside the chart to change the extreme points

Comment: I thought that you need to catch only in navigator. Sorry for that. Maybe better is catch mouseup on document / container? http://jsfiddle.net/8ydfw9ma/2/

Comment: I just modified a little bit yours. So this is what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/8ydfw9ma/3/. Thanks for your help.